# PBS: how to print history of jobs run and how to use script name as PBS_JOBNAME?

Tags: pbs, qsub, torque

New to qsub and HPCs. I got three small questions:

I want to have a better way of knowing which job script corresponds to the which stderr and stdout. I understand I can manually type in the job name and their stderr and stdout like this (well, right now I'm using `$PBS_JOBNAME.$PBS_JOBID` for `stderr` and `stdout`) but 6 months from now, I'd have a hard time knowing from which job script `stderr` and `stdout` `$PBS_JOBNAME.$PBS_JOBID` are generated. I'm thinking of using the job script name as the prefix for `stderr` and `stdout` so I can associate them easily but besides manually edit the script, is there some variable I can set to make this automatic?

```
  2 #PBS -N testjob
  3 #PBS -d /home/mydir/projects/test
  4 #PBS -q home
  5 #PBS -V
  6 #PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1
  7 #PBS -l walltime=1:00:00
  8 #PBS -M xxx@gmail.com
  9 #PBS -o $PBS_JOBNAME.$PBS_JOBID.out
 10 #PBS -e $PBS_JOBNAME.$PBS_JOBID.err
```

From the above script, I'm specifying running dir with `/home/mydir/projects/test`, I've tried `#PBS -d $PWD` but it didn't work. Is there a way also to automatically set the running dir as my current dir where I invoked the PBS job?

Lastly, I'd like to keep a record of jobs I've run. I can see the current running/queueing jobs with `qstat`, but after a few minutes the jobs is complete, `qstat` doesn't give any output. Is there some command that can print all the job history? Thanks!

Comment: Regarding the `-d` part of the question usual practice is to have `cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR` as the first command in the job script.

Comment: thanks! I also realized that I can use `#PBS -d .`

Answer (score 3):

You can see much of the history of completed jobs by running:

`tracejob <job ID>`

Run it without an argument to see the usage message. If you get permission errors on portions of the output, you may use the available options to suppress those parts. Use `-z` to get max info.

It will only go back a day by default, so you'll have to include "`-n <days>`" to see further back.

Comment: thanks. is there a command to look at jobs run by a particular user, i.e. I want to see all the jobs I run over the past few days.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, although if you have access to the server, you can search through the accounting logs (and/or job logs, if enabled).